# add_widget missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen' also parameter 'screen' unfulfilled

Tags: python, kivy

edit: it states that it wants `SM.add_widget(self, screen)` but if i add that it becomes an unresolved reference... I'll keep trying.

I apologise that I am a complete noob at this, this is my first more complex project without using a tutorial.
I can't for the life of me work out a way to correct this error. :/
I do not want to use a .kv file for this project.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "C:\Users\danti\PycharmProjects\IoU\main.py", line 188, in <module>
     SM.add_widget(screen)
 TypeError: add_widget() missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen'
```

I've tried a few formats to try solve it by myself but after 3 hours I'm lost.

when i hover my mouse over the

> (screen)

on the same line #188 it shows

> parameter 'screen' unfulfilled.

I'm lost as to what to look for anymore.

Here is my main.py file
(Error line is 10th up from bottom of main.py)

```
`from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Ellipse
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from database import DataBase


def invalidlogin():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Login',
                content=Label(text='Invalid username or password.'),
                size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()


def invalidform():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Form',
                content=Label(text='Please fill in all inputs\n with valid information.'),
                size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()


db = DataBase('users.txt')


class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass


def dbvalidatelgn(self, *args):
    if db.validate(self.email, self.password):
        Wlcm.current = self.email.text
        self.reset()
        SM.current = '_wlcm'
    else:
        invalidlogin()


class MyLogin(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLogin, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.inner = GridLayout()
        self.inner.cols = 2
        self.inner.rows = 2
        self.inner.size_hint = (1, .25)
        self.inner.pos_hint = {'x': 0, 'top': .8}

        self.inner.add_widget(Label(text='Email:'))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inner.add_widget(self.email)

        self.inner.add_widget(Label(text='Password:'))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inner.add_widget(self.password)

        self.submit = Button(text='Login')
        self.submit.font_size = 20
        self.add_widget(self.submit)
        self.submit.size_hint = (.8, .15)
        self.submit.pos_hint = {'top': .4, 'right': .9}
        self.submit.bind(on_release=dbvalidatelgn)

        self.noacct = Label(text='Don\'t have an account?')
        self.noacct.font_size = 14
        self.add_widget(self.noacct)
        self.noacct.size_hint = (.8, .15)
        self.noacct.pos_hint = {'top': .28, 'right': .9}

        self.newacct = Button(text='Create New Account', )
        self.newacct.font_size = 13
        self.add_widget(self.newacct)
        self.newacct.size_hint = (.6, .07)
        self.newacct.pos_hint = {'top': .15, 'right': .8}
        self.newacct.bind(on_release=self.new_acct)

        self.add_widget(self.inner)

    def new_acct(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = '_newacct'

    def Welcome(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = '_wlcm'


class NewAcct(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NewAcct, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.inner = GridLayout()
        self.inner.cols = 2
        self.inner.rows = 3
        self.inner.size_hint = (1, .25)
        self.inner.pos_hint = {'x': 0, 'top': .8}

        self.inner.add_widget(Label(text='Name:'))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inner.add_widget(self.name)

        self.inner.add_widget(Label(text='Email:'))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inner.add_widget(self.email)

        self.inner.add_widget(Label(text='Password:'))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inner.add_widget(self.password)

        self.create = Button(text='Submit')
        self.create.font_size = 20
        self.add_widget(self.create)
        self.create.size_hint = (.8, .15)
        self.create.pos_hint = {'top': .4, 'right': .9}

        self.hasacct = Label(text='Already have an account?')
        self.hasacct.font_size = 14
        self.add_widget(self.hasacct)
        self.hasacct.size_hint = (.8, .15)
        self.hasacct.pos_hint = {'top': .28, 'right': .9}

        self.retlog = Button(text='Return to Login', )
        self.retlog.font_size = 13
        self.add_widget(self.retlog)
        self.retlog.size_hint = (.6, .07)
        self.retlog.pos_hint = {'top': .15, 'right': .8}
        self.retlog.bind(on_release=self.has_acct)

        self.add_widget(self.inner)

    def has_acct(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = '_mylgn'

    def create_new(self):
        if self.name.text != '' and self.email.text != '' and self.email.text.count('@') == 1 and self.email.text.count(
                '.') > 0:
            if self.password != '':
                db.add_user(self.email.text, self.password.text, self.name.text)
            self.reset()
        else:
            invalidform()

    def login(self):
        self.reset()
        SM.current = '_mylgn'

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ''
        self.password.text = ''
        self.name.text = ''
        SM.current = '_mylgn'


class Wlcm(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Wlcm, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.wlcmtxt = Label(text='Login Successful!\nWelcome!')
        self.wlcmtxt.font_size = 30
        self.add_widget(self.wlcmtxt)

        self.retlog = Button(text='Log Out', )
        self.retlog.font_size = 16
        self.add_widget(self.retlog)
        self.retlog.size_hint = (.6, .07)
        self.retlog.pos_hint = {'top': .15, 'right': .8}
        self.retlog.bind(on_release=self.have_acct)

    def have_acct(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = '_mylgn'


screen = Screen()
screens = [MyLogin(name='_mylgn'), NewAcct(name='_newacct'), Wlcm(name='_wlcm')]
for screen in screens:
    SM.add_widget(screen)
#SM.add_widget(MyLogin(name='_mylgn'), screen)
#SM.add_widget(NewAcct(name='_newacct'), screen)
#SM.add_widget(Wlcm(name='_wlcm'), screen)
SM.current = '_mylgn'

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLogin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
`
```

Here is my database.py file incase that helps

```
import datetime
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, filenaem):
        self.filename = filenaem
        self.users = None
        self.file = None
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        self.file = open(self.filename, 'r')
        self.users = {}

        for line in self.file:
            email, password, name, created = line.strip().split(';')
            self.users[email] = (password, name, created)

        self.file.close()

    def get_user(self, email):
        if email in self.users:
            return self.users[email]
        else:
            return -1

    def add_user(self, email, password, name):
        if email.strip() not in self.users:
            self.users[email.strip()] = (password.strip(), name.strip(), DataBase.get_date())
            self.save()
        else:
            print('This email already exists!')
            return -1

    def validate(self, email, password):
        if self.get_user(email) != -1:
            return self.users[email][0] == password
        else:
            return False

    def save(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as f:
            for user in self.users:
                f.write(user + ';' + self.users[user][0] + ';' + self.users[user][1] + ';' + self.users[user][2] + '\n')

    @staticmethod
    def get_date():
        return str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add_widget()` method of `ScreenManager` is an instance method and is expected to be called on an instance of `ScreenManager`. In your code, `SM` is a `ScreenManager` class, it is not an instance of `ScreenManager`. So you need to create an instance by doing something like:

```
sm = SM()
screens = [MyLogin(name='_mylgn'), NewAcct(name='_newacct'), Wlcm(name='_wlcm')]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)
```

Your `build()` method probably should look like:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
```